# Xcode7.0.1＋Swift2.0でAlamofire2.0を使うとNSURLErrorDomainが返ってくる

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

下記の環境で、Alamofireを使ったJSONデータの取得を試みています。

・Xcode：7.0.1
・Swift：2.0
・Alamofire：2.0.2

```
    Alamofire.request(
        .GET,
        "http://hogehoge.jp/testjson.php",
        parameters: ["t" : 1],
        encoding: .JSON
    ).response{
        (request, response, data, error) in
        print(data)
    };
```

上記のソースで、コンパイルは正常に通ったのですが、
実際に動かしてみると、下から2行目のprint(data)の時点で
errorに「NSURLErrorDomain」が返却されてしまいます。
指定したURLにアクセスすると、正常にデータが取得できるのですが、
どうしてこんなことになるのかがわかりません。

どなたか、教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

お使いのiOSが9.0以上なら ATS が原因かもしれません
http://shirakiya.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/10/03/234816

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
教えていただいたURLをもとに設定して、クリーン→ビルドを行ってみたのですが、やはり同じエラーが発生してしまいました。
アクセスしようとしているURLがSSLに対応していないことが原因なのでしょうか？

Comment: 一度、「info.plist」のキーをキレイにして設定し直したところ、正常にデータを取得することができました！
ありがとうございました。